# Is there a way to achieve this with a material?

Tags: rendering

I have multiple objects that I need to have separate transparent renders of. The problem is that they are in front of each other. I know that I can disable the objects from being rendered but this doesn't give me the effect I need.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve (simplified):

**Render of all objects**

[image: Render of a circle in front of a square]

**Render of the square I get when I disable the circle from being rendered**

[image: Render of the square I get when I disable the circle from being rendered]

**Render of the square I would like to have**

[image: Render of the square I would like to have]

Can this be achieved by giving the circle a special material or what could I do?

Comment: You can use a holdout material, enable holdout in visibility property of the object or enable the holdout option in a collection. - 
[holdout material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html) - 
[holdout visibility](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/visibility.html?highlight=holdout) - 
[holdout collection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html?highlight=holdout)

Comment: Thank you :) Exactly what I was looking for!